# Script to automate the passing credentials to next page

Tags: javascript, html, single-sign-on

I have one URL which asks me to " click here to login" then the next page loads.
once the next page loads I need to pass the credential. tried below script but didn't work

```html
document.getElementsByClassName('click_hereTo_login')[0].click();

$( document ).ready(function() 
{ if document.location.href=="https://example.com/secondpage"
then {
  document.getElementById('id').value="12322";
document.getElementById('password').value="4444";
document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0].click();
}})
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all your if is not written correctly. It should be:

```
if (document.location.href=="https://example.com/secondpage"){
    document.getElementById('id').value="12322";
    document.getElementById('password').value="4444";
    document.getElementsByClassName('login')[0].click();
}
```

The another problem here is, that your script runs from scratch on both pages. If you want to pass data from page to page without backend, you can use either **query string** or **localstorage** to store the data somewhere and then access it from another page.

```
let id = localStorage.getItem('id');

// get the input element 
let idInput = document.getElementById('id');

// check if we are one second page
if(idInput) {
    document.getElementById('id').value = id;
}

// Save id on login click
document.querySelector('.login').addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('id', 1234);
});
```

Comment: thanks for prompt reply, but this is not working.
example is gmail.com. i am passing the script in first page, . so the script should be able to pass the id in first page then password in second page.

Comment: You can store the id in localStorage when you are on the first page. And then retrieve it from localStorage on the second page.

Comment: almost this helped, but failed to capture the credentials  example site is.

https://tradefinance.hdfcbank.com/hdfctfportalweb/